# Understand of Unijunction Transistor

Tags: semiconductors

Unijunction transistor is a semiconductor device that can be represented as shown:

[image]

It forms a voltage divider with a diode pointing towards middle of divider marked as \$\eta V_{BB}\$ (where \$\eta\$ is voltage divider ratio, I assume).
If a circuit is built with discrete components, using two resistors and a diode, then the behavior of such circuit becomes fairly similar to UJT.

***But what kind of function should such transistor perform?*** Not as an amplifier, that is for sure. Since major current flow comes from emitter node and emitter is control node (something like base/gate in conventional BJT of MOSFET), while either of base nodes provides with minority current flow. ***What is that useful for anyway? Where would one use its behavior as something useful?***

Also, it doesn't seem as a switch to me. Since, again, major current flow comes from emitter and emitter should be the controlling node in this case. While base provides with minor current flow.

From experimenting with such transistor on breadboard I saw that increasing emitter voltage \$V_E\$ increases \$I_{b2}\$ slightly but increases \$I_{b1}\$ greatly. And with emitter-open, there is a current very little current flow (compared to emitter current) between B2 and B1, since there is no junction between those two but rather semi-conducting path.

***Also, how does UJT achieve negative resistance?*** With \$V_E\$ increased beyond threshold of UJT, the emitter current injected into the base is increased and \$R_{B1}\$ is decreased. But although it is decreased, the current through it still increases. If there would be a negative resistance, then the current through B1 would decrease as \$V_E\$ would increase.

I am mainly wondering, whether this kind of transistor is worth of troubling and dealing with.

Comment: Finding one to buy will give you a headache. They are outdated since about 1970.

Comment: @Janka Actually, I have few (you can see I wrote something about experimenting with one) - 2N2646. But I guess they are obsolete for a reason.

Comment: Many years ago I needed one before they were in production, and I simulated one with an NPN and a PNP. I can't remember the details, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unijunction was/is used as an oscillator; The diode breaks down, injects current, the channel becomes highly conductive until the current returns to near zero electron flow.

Used like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWHINB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Diode breaks down? What does that mean? That it drops threshold voltage of 0.7V? Anyway, is there any other known usage of UJT besides relaxation oscillator?

Comment: GE produced the only versions I know about. And I think the threshold was 50% or 70% of the VDD, set by how far up the semiconductor bar the diode was implanted. We need to view this as a form of SCR. And, not surprisingly, GE was a big producer of SCRs.

Comment: What does threshold mean for UJT? A 0.7V diode voltage drop plus voltage drop across internal resistance between junction of emitter to B1 node \$R_{b1}\$?

Comment: Also, it has been said that UJT has negative resistance; that is \$ R_{B1} \$. With increase in \$V_E\$ beyond threshold voltage the UJT's diode conducts more current through \$ R_{B1} \$, which makes the n-conducting region less resistive. But still, if \$V_E\$ increases so does the current through B1 node. In case of negative resistance, with voltage increase current drops.

Answer (score 2):

The negative resistance characteristic is caused by conductivity modulation in the interbase region below the junction. In order to enter the negative resistance region, the emitter current must exceed a certain peak current. In that case of the 2N2646 that was specified to be less than 5uA. So, when used as a timer or relaxation oscillator, a higher resistance could be  used for the 2N2647 and perhaps the capacitor size could be reduced, to get the same time.

**NOTE:** You **cannot** make a UJT with a diode and two resistors (any more than you can make a BJT with two diodes).. it will behave similarly to the UJT until you reach the peak emitter current, then nothing will happen except the emitter current will increase.

UJTs were commonly used to trigger thyristors. The brief pulse of substantial current (available between base B1 and ground) was close to ideal for triggering the gate of an SCR or triac. You could couple it through a pulse transformer if you wanted isolation. So, good for phase controls and such like.

They were also used in such diverse circuits as time delay relays, metronomes and so on. Remember that in those days NE555 timers and microcontrollers were not available so what is so simple in 2019 was much more of a effort to build with what was available. CMOS gates were not widely available either until the early 1970s. Here is an example of a circuit (from the GE SCR manual 5th edition ca. 1972):

[image]

R6 is chosen such that the positive temperature coefficient of the silicon interbase resistance nominally compensates for the negative tempco of Vd at the peak current for trigger. (recall that the trigger voltage is \$\eta V_{BB} + V_D\$)

True UJTs were more-or-less obsolete by 1975, though their (quite different) namesake the 4-layer [PUT](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N6027-D.PDF) (programmable unijunction transistor) was viable for quite a bit longer- and even made the transition to surface mount (though I doubt they get design-ins today you can still buy them through conventional distributors).

In truth they were simple for their function, and the time, but they were not very precise or flexible devices. The value of \$\eta\$ (the intrinsic standoff ratio) was not well specified- 0.56 to 0.75 for the 2N2646 and the peak current was quite high- 5uA. The relatively low (and poorly specified) interbase resistance (4.7K to 9.1K) meant that the device drew quite a bit of quiescent current.

Comment: I am looking at 2N2646 UJT datasheet (here: https://www.voti.nl/docs/2n2646.pdf). It says that peak current for it is max. 5 uA. So, what happens after emitter current exceeds that value? And valley current is also specified to be min. 4 mA. Does voltage between base1 and emitter decrease as emitter current is increased beyond peak current?

Comment: The emitter voltage decreases to close to the B1 voltage after triggering (saturation voltage). 

So if the η*Vbb+Vd is 8V, and supply voltage is 12V and the Vd is 0.7V then the resistor must be between  about 2.8K and 800K for it to function, not accounting for tolerances etc.

Comment: Once the current exceeds the peak current (which is guaranteed to be less than 5uA), triggering occurs and current flows from the emitter to B1 (in addition to the current flowing from B2). So if there is a resistor from the emitter to the supply voltage, that resistor must be low enough value that the maximum trigger current flows  or it may never trigger and just sit there at near the trigger voltage. Similarly, after it triggers the current through that resistor, after the capacitor has discharged, must be less than the minimum valley current or the UJT may  never turn off.

Comment: Yes, it is true, what you say. However, after I tried all this on breadboard with 2N2646 UJT I noticed one strange thing. After triggering UJT into negative resistance region \$ I_E\$ jumps from \$ 1\mu A \$ or so to \$ 2 mA \$ or so; it cannot be progressively moved down the negative resistance slope (from peak point) - \$ I_E / U_{EB1} \$ quiescent point moves somewhere in the middle of that negative region curve. **But why? Why doesn't it progressively moves down the slope towards valley point?**

Comment: I used multi-turn potentiometer in order to achieve gradual movement of quiescent point instead of jumping from few \$ \mu A\$ to few \$ mA \$ in a blink of a second, but failed to do so... After it jumps to middle of negative resistance curve it can be moved up and down the negative resistance curve progressively.

Comment: You're changing the voltage from emitter to B1 at the same time. If you have a capacitor there it will drop down the curve momentarily.

Comment: Yes, I am changing voltage form emitter to B1. But how else could I trigger UJT? I think you didn't get my question here. I want to move quiescent point progressively up to the peak point, then progressively down to valley point; with a potentiometer as voltage divider (no capacitor). But am unable to do so because right after I reach peak point, \$ I_E / U_{EB1} \$ point drops to somewhere in the middle of negative resistance slope instantaneously. And now, I am wondering, why cannot I do that progressively.

Comment: So to have it stable you need to add enough resistance in series that the net resistance is positive, so resistor must be greater than the maximum slope of the negative resistance curve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approximate replacement for a unijunction transistor
(remove the capacitor, and make the resistors 100,000 ohms)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmE6fT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>